# How to find the least number of extractions to make the word QATAR?

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization

The riddle is as follows:

> A local library has lended its catalog card cabinet so it can be used
> in a raffle. The raffle prize is a luxurious travel to the Middle East
> for vacations to an employee from the toy company.
>
> Each drawer has a label indicating the contents, a set of colored
> cards which have a letter printed, so when you take out a card from
> each drawer you can read the word QATAR (the nation destination of the
> prize).
>
> These drawers are ordered from left to right in a row. (With Q being
> in the left and A on the right) with the labels as follows:
>
> Drawer Q: 7 red cards and 8 blue cards
>
> Drawer T: 6 red cards and 8 blue cards
>
> Drawer R: 6 red cards and 8 blue cards
>
> Drawer A: 7 red cards and 6 blue cards
>
> Given this information, how many cards should be taken out at random
> one-by-one and without looking in order to be sure to get the word
> QATAR but with all sharing the same color?

The alternatives given are as follows:

1. 24
2. 27
3. 25
4. 30

I found this riddle in my *Logical challenges book* from the 2000s. It seems to be an adaptation from a reprinted edition of the Martin Gardner's Puzzle carnival from 1970s.

This is my attempt at solving the problem:

If the employee takes out a card from the first drawer, we don't know if he takes red or blue.

I assumed that we can be sure that, by taking out all the red and blue cards from the drawers T and R, we have covered all the options forming the word QTR.

The problem is the A.

Then I thought that the worst case scenario would be taking out a color contrary to what it was obtained first, the combination obtaining more would be, taking out all the 7 red cards plus 1 blue.

Thus I'm getting

$1+14+14+7+2=28$

But it seems that I'm off by one according to the answer. What could be wrong in my interpretation? My logic is that if he takes out one red then he would get all the blue, thus the additional extraction would necessarily be red (assuming the initial letter was in red and he is aiming for that color). In this case it is assured that the number of extractions is more because looking for red will imply having an additional extraction rather than blue for the letter A. But again, this doesn't seem to comply with the choices.

Now there is an aspect which has left me confused and I hope it can be addressed by an answer. The problem doesn't specifically indicate that a contestant has to start drawing lots or taking out cards from the left drawer, he could begin in the center or any. But I assumed that starting the left seems more logical.

But, T and R have the same number of colored cards so it doesn't matter does it? Please include as many details as possible in answers.

What could be wrong?

Comment: The same user posted [this questiion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031254/how-to-find-the-least-number-of-extractions-to-make-the-word-waay-tv) to math.se, which is essentially the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from RobPratt's answer, here's some extra description:

**1. Reword the problem in a way that makes it easier to solve.**

Let's ignore the double A for a moment.  Another way of thinking about the problem is to realise that it is solved *exactly when* we know for a fact that we have one of each colour of letter.

Why?  Because if we don't know that we have both colours of every letter, then all the letters bar one could be blue and the other be red.

To put the double A condition back in, we now also know that this means we have to know we have at least 2 of each colour.

**2. How do we know we have at least one of each colour from a drawer?**

Well, the worst case would be to keep drawing out cards that are in the biggest set from the drawer until we had all of those... and then take one more.  Since we can't avoid this case, this is the only way we can be certain.

How would we expand this for A?  Well we know that if we take out all of the biggest set *plus 2* we definitely have 2 of each colour.

*This leads to:*
Q: worst case is 8 blue + 1 red = 9 cards <- definitely 1 of each
T: worst case is 8 blue + 1 red = 9 cards <- definitely 1 of each
R: worst case is 8 blue + 1 red = 9 cards <- definitely 1 of each
A: worst case is 7 red + 2 blue = 9 cards <- definitely 2 of each

**3. But that's not right... We forgot something!**
Correct, the last step is to realise that of the 4 drawers you choose from, you only need take enough from the *last* one to be sure you have enough of *any* colour, not both.

Why?  Because you have made it guaranteed that whichever of the two colours you pull from the last drawer, all your other piles definitely have that colour in them (in fact, you made sure they had both!)

**4. Redoing the last drawer selection:**
So if we choose the order in which we pick drawers, picking A last, we would indeed get RobPratt's answer of 30.  Because we only need pick 3 cards to be sure that at least two of them are the same (worst cases are R -> B -> ? or B -> R -> ?) and 9 + 9 + 9 + 3 = 30

However, what if we pick Q, T or R last?  It doesn't matter to the initial pulls, because we know they all take 9 pulls in their worst cases to get the right number of each colour.  BUT it is quicker to get 1 of any colour from a drawer - you only need 1 pull!

This leads to a different conclusion that you need 9 + 9 + 9 + 1 = 28 pulls.
So now I am wondering whether you were right (but with incorrect math!)
OR (which is more likely) I have missed something.

Comment: I will comment on my own answer that, on re-reading, there is the possibility in the wording that you must select from the drawers "in order" (in which case it is 30). However, I read it as "in order to be sure" which does not mean that you are forced to select left-to-right (in which case it could be 28).

Comment: Under the assumption that the number of picks from each drawer must be specified in advance, your solution of 28 is optimal.

Comment: Phew - I was suddenly concerned that perhaps I had done it incorrectly!  I liked your answer, I just thought there might be an alternative interpretation worth exploring. :)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing 9Q, 9T, 9R, and 3A yields at least 1 of each color for QTR and at least 2 of at least one color for A.  The total is 30.

Note that your sum is 38, not 28.

Comment: I think the wording it is a little bit misleading. I'm getting the idea that in your first case, 8Q guarantees, all blue, or red and blue, 7 T guarantees all are blue or red plus blue, the same for R, while for A. I guess its because the first extraction can be blue, the next one red, and the next one would be blue or red. So adding all these becomes into 25. Is this the interpretation from your answer?.